# Delete anything outside an area

Tags: mask, autodesk-sketchbook-pro

If i have outlined an object, say a car, and i have added a red air brush around to give it a color, how could i remove all color outside the outline of the car? Masking etc. ?

Comment: what about eraser tool??

Comment: Well i was wondering if there was a faster way then erasing outside the outline of the same object on multiple layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a duplicate of the outline you made of the car.
Select the outline and the red air brush art.
Open the Pathfinder palette and select Divide.
Ungroup the selection.
Delete the unwanted portions.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm sure SketchBook Pro doesn't have a Pathfinder palette. Illustrator does of course. Not sure why this was accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You simply make a selection of the car (any way you choose = quick select/magic wand/pen path/ctrl click on the layer thumbnail/mask/etc.) and inverse the selection (ctr + shift + i).

The inverse selection will do just that: select everything outside of the current selection. In your case, everything except the car.

This can literally be achieved with 2-clicks of the mouse.

Comment: can you inverse selection to only outside but not inside of selection?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean.

In order to inverse your selection, you need to have a selection to begin with. 

In this case, he'd make a selection of the car (which allows control of everything within the selection/car). Then, simply inverse it (which changes the control to everything outside the selection/car).